# How should i verify cookies for username and password in HTML page

Tags: php, html, session

I am totally new to this webpage design. I designed a login page with HTML and PHP. After logged in php opening a HTML page. I dont want user access this page directly by giving url of the page, without logging in. I searched about PHP sessions, But i am not sure.

How my html page should verify cookies for password and if its not there how i should redirect to login page.

Comment: Check if the user session is set, if it isn't show something like permission denied. If it is set, show them the page you want the user logged in to get.

Comment: YOU CAN NOT VALIDATE PHP SESSIONS / COOKIES THROUGH HTML PAGE

Answer (score -1):

PHP has sessions ,you need to start session with  session_start(); before using any session variable in php site.

```
<?php
session_start();

//check if the user session is set , suppose user logged in with username and password and you get the user details 
//from database : user_id , user_name , user_firstname etc set this values in session 

// check if user_id is present in session and show the page 

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) AND !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
 // show HTML page
}else{
// redirect to home page.
}

?>
```